# Adding a word in cite. For example: According to ABC's studies (2011) in Biblatex

Tags: biblatex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp,maxbibnames=9,maxcitenames=2,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{ABC01,
  author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B. and C},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
 According to \textcite{ABC01}, parallel...

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Outcome:

```
According to Author et al. (2001), parallel...
```

How to get:

```
According to Author et al.'s studies (2001), parallel...
```

Comment: If you're mainly concerned about the possessive citation see [Author name of \textcite as possessive](//tex.stackexchange.com/a/307461) (this answer specifically; the accepted answer is out of date due to changes in `biblatex`. The general syntax of all `biblatex` cite commands is `...cite[prenote][postnote]{citekey}` If you only want the prenote you need to use `...cite[prenote][]{citekey}`; if you only want the postnote you can use `...cite[postnote]{citekey}`.

Comment: It looks as though you want slightly more flexibility than the possessive cite. I guess I would go for `According to \citeauthor{ABC01}'s studies \autocite*{ABC01}, parallel` here.

Comment: Thanks. however, it came to be 'Author et al.’s studies (ibid.), parallel'
The years is 'ibid' which is weird

Comment: In the MWE I don't get "ibid." (see my answer). It is possible, though that you get "ibid." if you cited the same source before. It would be the same with `\textcite`, though, so that should be OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For situations like this I would use a combination of `\citeauthor` and `\autocite*`. The starred version of `\autocite` (similar commands exist for all `\...cite` commands where it makes sense) will omit the author from the citation label and is particularly useful if the author names have been mentioned manually or with `\citeauthor` before.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp,maxbibnames=9,maxcitenames=2,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
According to \citeauthor{sigfridsson}'s studies \autocite*{sigfridsson}, parallel \dots

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: According to Sigfridsson and Ryde’s studies (1998), parallel ...]

Comment: Thanks, just a couple more question:
1. Will it work for \parencite, \textcite too?
2. Did it seem do not work on cross-reference?

Comment: @user193541 1. Yes, that should work for `\parencite` and `\textcite` as well. Did you have any trouble with it? 2. I'm afraid I don't quite understand that question. Can you rephrase it, please?

Comment: thanks.
\parenciteauthor{}  =  \citeauthor{}. How about \autocite*{}?

Comment: @user193541 Sorry, I'm a bit slow (it's quite late where I am), I still don't quite understand what you mean. As far as I know standard `biblatex` doesn't define `\parenciteauthor`, so I don't get what `\parenciteauthor{}`=`\citeauthor{}` is supposed to mean.

Comment: thanks. I compile the above latex. However, it does not do cross-referencing. Especially on `Sigfridsson and Ryde`, but it does on `(1998)`.

Comment: @aan Yes, this is normal and expected. Usually `biblatex` does not link the author name in a citation, because there are some stylistic and technical difficulties doing that in more complex citation styles.

Comment: so is there a method to link the author name in a citation?

Comment: @aan In some cases there is, yes. For `\citeauthor` this is already discussed in your follow-up question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/505035/35864

Comment: there is still some issue with the proposed answer