# How to have generate "Author's studies (2008)" in latex

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing, back-referencing

I want to write below in my text:

```
According to Author et al.'s studies (2008), blablabal...
```

If I used:

```
According to \textcite{author1}'s studies
```

It will become:

```
According to Author et al. (2008)'s studies, blablabal...
```

Comment: What about writing “according to the study of Author et al (2008)”

Comment: Isn't that pretty much the same as your earlier question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/501871/35864?

Comment: Again I would just say `According to \citeauthor{sigfridsson}'s studies \autocite*{sigfridsson}`.

Comment: On second glance this is *exactly* the same question as it stands now, so I closed this one as a duplicate. If there is a significant difference in this question compared to the other one, please edit the question to make that clear and ping me. I will then vote to reopen.

Answer (score 0):

With packages (e.g., `biblatex`, `natbib`) that provide facilities to split citations in their components (e.g., title, authors, year) one can use (using fo instance `\biblatex` commands)

```
According to \citeauthor{author1}'s studies (\citeyear{author1}), blablabla ...
```

to obtain the desired result. Clearly, a new citation command can be defined to automatise the procedure:

```
\newcommand{\mycite}[2]{\citeauthor{#1}'s #2 \citeyear{#1}}
```

Comment: thanks. However `\citeauthor{author1}'s studies (\citeyear{author1})` does not have cross-referencing. But the output is correct.

Comment: could you elaborate more on `\newcommand{\mycite}[2]{\citeauthor{#1}'s #2 \citeyear{#1}}`? what is `#2`? I tried `#1` as `author1`.

Comment: #2 is the text you want to appears between the authors and the year

Comment: Since the OP is using an `authoryear`-like style `\parencite*{sigfridsson}` is a much better alternative to `(\citeyear{sigfridsson})`.

Comment: @Guido, thanks. I compile the above latex. However, it does not do cross-referencing. Especially on `author1`, but it does on `(year)`.