# Cross Referencing for Author name of \textcite as possessive not working (BibLatex)

Tags: biblatex, citing

I am using the

```
\newcommand{\mycite}[2]{\citeauthor{kazem2003design}'s \citeyear{kazem2003design}}
```

However, the cross-referencing for the author is not working. 
For the year is working.

Outcome:
[image]

In here `According to Kazem et al.’s studies (2003), blablabla`

1. `Kazem et al cross-referencing` is not working.
2. `(2003)` cross-referencing is working (it change to blue colour text)

Code:

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

According to \citeauthor{kazem2003design}'s studies \autocite*{kazem2003design}, blablabla 

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Reference:

```
@inproceedings{kazem2003design,
  title={Design considerations for a background auditory display to aid pilot situation awareness},
  author={Kazem, Mandana LN and Noyes, Janet M and Lieven, Nicholas J},
  year={2003},
  organization={Georgia Institute of Technology}
}
```

Comment: "is not working" is not realy helpful! I'm sure you know what is not working but we do not have your informations! Can you please explain better? Do you want it also in blue? BTW: please add the call of package `hyperref` to your code so that we can see the color too on our computers ...

Comment: @Mensch, thanks. I want the `Author name` to become blue like the `year`. so that when I click on it, it direct to the referencing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you have some errors in your given code I corrected in the following MWE.

To solve your issue add the code

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthor}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printnames{labelname}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

to your preamble.

With the following complete MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{kazem2003design,
  title={Design considerations for a background auditory display to aid pilot situation awareness},
  author={Kazem, Mandana LN and Noyes, Janet M and Lieven, Nicholas J},
  year={2003},
  organization={Georgia Institute of Technology}
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[british]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
  style=authoryear, 
  backend=biber, 
  giveninits % <========================================================
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} % \jobname to use the bib file created with filecontents
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\usepackage[unicode,colorlinks,citecolor=blue]{hyperref} % <============

\newcommand{\mycite}[1]{\citeauthor{#1}'s \citeyear{#1}} % <============

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthor} % <====================================
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printnames{labelname}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}


\begin{document}

According to \citeauthor{kazem2003design}'s studies \autocite*{kazem2003design}, blablabla 

\mycite{kazem2003design} % <============================================

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

you get the following result:

[image: resulting pdf]

Please see that `\citeyear` has no link in my added corrected command `\mycite`!

Comment: thanks. There will be two issues. 1. Will it create all the author name appear in bibliography rather than using Harvard referencing where the first name is getting short. 2. It does not change to blue color as in cross-referencing that link to citition.

Comment: To get the blue color use command `\usepackage[unicode,colorlinks,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}` in the preamble. See updated answer. I'm not sure if uncommenting `giveninits` gives you the harvard style you want (you did not explain in your question exactly what you want) but then take care of the resulting warning ...

Comment: thanks. If I use `\textcite` and `\parencite`, it only link the `year` and not both `author and year`. Is there other format?

Comment: @aan We do not like "living" questions (expanded or completly changed questions in comments) here. Your comment above is a new question, please ask a new question therefore! My answer here  answered your given question ... ...